# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2 for ListType[array(float32, 2d, C)]

Tags: python, pandas, list, scikit-learn

I have embeddings_ as looks like as follows -

```
ListType[array(float32, 2d, C)]([[[ -1.2124693    0.9572239 ]
 [  0.56466156   0.7211671 ]
 [ -1.0872451   -2.051641  ]
 ...
 [-54.282215    32.87948   ]
 [  2.5681546    0.12829414]
 [  2.2808175    1.5369933 ]], [[ 1.669828   -2.4118974 ]
 [-0.22858042 -0.6938448 ]
 [ 1.5701272   0.7148179 ]
 ...
 [ -9.497137   25.826427 ]
 [-17.761719   15.798782 ]
 [-17.39355    26.622911 ]], ...])
```

Now cluster the data. As a first attempt let’s try the traditional approach: K-Means. In this case we can solve one of the hard problems for K-Means clustering – choosing the right k value, giving the number of clusters we are looking for. In this case we know the answer is exactly 10. We will use sklearns K-Means implementation looking for 10 clusters in the original dimensional data.

```
# Dimension reduction and clustering libraries
import umap
import sklearn.cluster as cluster
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score, adjusted_mutual_info_score

kmeans_labels = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=10).fit_predict(updating_mapper.embeddings_)
```

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    657                     "into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric'") from e
    658         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
--> 659             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
    660                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
```

The error message I got -

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

How do I reduce dim 3 into dimension 2 in order to apply K-mean clustering?

Comment: do you have a redundant dimension? you can slice it, or use numpy.reshape()

Comment: @RitwickJha thank you for the response!But it is `ListType[array(float32, 2d, C)]`, I can't used numpy.reshape()

Answer (score 0):

is one of your dimensions redundant? that is, is your data point a vector? then you can simply do

```
import numpy as np

a1 = [[[1,2,3], [8,9,3], [4,5,6], [3,4,5]]]

b = np.array(a1)
print(b.shape)
#(1, 4, 3)

b1 = np.reshape(b,(b.shape[1],-1))
print(b1.shape)
#(4, 3)

b2 = a1[0][:]
print(np.array(b2).shape)
#(4, 3)
```

if each of your data point is 2 dimensional then you will have to think about how to perform clustering. you can try and flatten it but then you will most likely mis represent the data and the clusters will not be suitable. maybe consider a function that will squish your 2d point to a vector, or write k means on your own with a distance metric that can be applied to 2d data points.

Comment: thank you for the response! but for result ``` b1 = np.reshape(b,(b.shape[1],-1))
print(b1.shape)```  if  ```print(b.shape)``` is (2,4,3) so b1 I need ```(8,3)```

Comment: well then do that. but as i said in the last paragraph that will not be very meaningful to cluster. you are clustering 2D points by flattening them. the dimensions will loose meaning. maybe do PCA to convert 2D space to 1D space and then cluster

Comment: Yes, You are correct but I am using umap for dimension reduction as it is non-linear unsupervised learning., I can't use PCA for this. It is the requirement to use umap and apply k-mean clustering.